# Select TD that contain A span in CSS

Tags: css

If I have generated HTML:

```
<td><span class='n'>123<span class='thousand'>124</span>124</span></td>
<td>not a number</td>
```

From from `Vue.js` template:

```
<td>{{ num | integer }}</td>
<td>{{ str }}</td>
```

How to select `td` that contain a `span.n` using CSS? I want to align it to right

Comment: `td span.n{ float: right }`

Comment: @DeepakBandi It will align only text in span, but not in `td`

Comment: Oh that wont be possible by just using CSS

Comment: also there seems to be some markup errors your closing `<td/>` is missing  or typo and your `<spans>` are nested and/or not closed

Comment: @happymacarts Span `.n` has child `.thousand` and is closed properly.

Comment: sorry its getting late i keep saying i am going to bed but the td was not closed right (it is now)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for parent selector that is not implemented in CSS yet (wait for CSSv4).

You can use js/jQuery to select parent:

```
$('span.n').closest('td').addClass('text-align-left')
```

---

If your text is wrapped in `span` and is only text that must be aligned in that `td`, than you can use such css:

```
td span.n {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

It will remove `span` align as inline element, but will make it full width with text align to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using one of these lines:

```
td .n{float:right;}
td span.n{float:right;}
td > .n{float:right;}
td > span.n{float:right;}
```